# Currency Field as Workflow Criteria

Tags: workflow, currency

I created a workflow on opportunities with one criterion being 'Amount greater than 19,999'. The workflow saved without an issue but didn't respect this individual criterion (i.e. performed an email alert on an opportunity less than £19,999). My suspicion is that this is caused by the format of the amount. All examples in Salesforce documentation refer to currency fields without a £ or $ and without any commas. Can anyone confirm that a comma in the amount field would be what is causing this workflow to not function as expected?

I would run a simple test in our sandbox but we have so many workflows that I would need to deactivate so as not to send out any other alert emails that I was hoping someone may have run into this problem before and save me the hassle.

Comment: Are you using the symbols in the workflow rule? I'm pretty sure the IsoCurrencyCode field uses the ISO standards rather than the symbols, so £ would be ISPICKVAL(IsoCurrencyCode,"GBP")

Comment: Do you have multiple currencies enabled?

Comment: Can you please update your question with description of how exactly your current criteria looks like?

Answer (score 1):

You can restrict the sending of emails from Sandbox:
In Setup, type 'deliver' in Quick Find box at top of menu on left.  Click on 'Email deliverability' and select 'System only' or none.

Answer (score 0):

When typing in numbers, do not use any punctuation, especially commas.

## Correct

```
Field greater than 19999
```

## Incorrect

```
Field greater than 19,999
```

The latter translates to: "Field greater than 19 or field greater than 999".

For text fields, include quotes if there is a comma:

## Correct

```
Field equals "Doe, John"
```

## Incorrect

```
Field equals Doe, John
```

The latter would translate to "Field equals Doe or Field equals John", instead of the intended effect ("Field equals 'Doe, John'").